# Play Specs2 test: ReactiveMongoPlugin Error

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework, akka, specs2

I'm using Play Framework, Akka Persistent actors and MongoDB.

When I run my Specs2 Test with FakeApplication, java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError is thrown and the cause is the following:

```
Caused by: @6md6ke2n9: ReactiveMongoPlugin Error
    at play.modules.reactivemongo.ReactiveMongoPlugin$.current(ReactiveMongoPlugin.scala:83)
    at play.modules.reactivemongo.ReactiveMongoPlugin$.db(ReactiveMongoPlugin.scala:78)
    at models.daos.TaskDAO$.<init>(TaskDAO.scala:25)
    at models.daos.TaskDAO$.<clinit>(TaskDAO.scala)
```

This occurs when ReactiveMongoPlugin.db is invoked.

```
def db: reactivemongo.api.DB = ReactiveMongoPlugin.db

  val futureCollection: Future[JSONCollection] = {
    val db = ReactiveMongoPlugin.db
    // ...
  }
```

This problem has occurred since I started using PersistentActor. I don't know if there is some conflict between akka-persistence and reactive-mongo dependencies. The following is my build.sbt:

```
name := "fmcloud"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

resolvers := ("Atlassian Releases" at "https://maven.atlassian.com/public/") +: resolvers.value

resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots")
resolvers += "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "javax.inject" % "javax.inject" % "1",
  "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.10.5.0.akka23",
  "net.codingwell" %% "scala-guice" % "4.0.0-beta5",
  "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "3.3.1",
  "org.webjars" % "angularjs" % "1.3.8",
  "org.webjars" % "angular-ui-bootstrap" % "0.12.0",
  "org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "1.10.17" % "test",
  "com.mohiva" %% "play-silhouette-testkit" % "2.0" % "test",
  "com.mohiva" %% "play-silhouette" % "2.0",
  "org.json" % "json" % "20141113",
  "javax.websocket" % "javax.websocket-client-api" % "1.1",
  "org.glassfish.tyrus" % "tyrus-container-grizzly-client" % "1.4",
  "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-testkit_2.11" % "2.3.10",
  "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-persistence-experimental_2.11" % "2.3.10",
  "com.github.ironfish" %% "akka-persistence-mongo-casbah"  % "0.7.5" % "compile"
)
```

EDIT: Proably this was an IntelliJ IDEA issue. I updated both IntelliJ and Scala plugin and now there is no ReactiveMongoPlugin Error. Unfortunately now all test-cases work except one (which involves the PersistentActor).
It is still thrown java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError but the cause is different:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application
at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$current$1.apply(Play.scala:71)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$current$1.apply(Play.scala:71)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at play.api.Play$.current(Play.scala:71)
    at models.daos.TaskDAO$.<init>(TaskDAO.scala:26)
    at models.daos.TaskDAO$.<clinit>(TaskDAO.scala)
    ... 19 more
```

EDIT2: I noticed that this error occurs only when I use TestActorRef of my persistent actor.

Comment: Do you want reactive mongo runnning? Is this a unit test or integration test?

Comment: It is a unit test. I want reactivemongo to run.. how can I check it?